# Explanation of two argument variant for arctan

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Can someone please explain why $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$ has the additional conditions based on what the value of x and y are?  I'm most specifically interested in the second equation:  $$\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \pi $$

How does this change when y is an imaginary number and x is a real number?

[image: arctan formula]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first piece of the definition says it all. $\arctan$ is a map $\mathbb R\to(-\frac\pi 2,\frac \pi 2)$, so the other adjustments are an attempt to return the correct argument for the point $(x,y)$; this argument can lie in $(-\pi,\pi]$.

For example, for the complex number $-1-i$ (taking $x=y=-1$), the argument should be $-\frac {3\pi}{4}$. But $\arctan\frac{-1}{-1}=\arctan 1=\frac\pi 4$. The adjustment turns this into $\frac\pi 4-\pi=-\frac{3\pi}{4}$ as desired.

Reminder: The (principal) argument of a nonzero complex number is usually defined to be the angle in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ between the positive real axis and the ray from the origin through the point representing the complex number. Other definitions are possible by specifying a different range of possible values.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how this changes when y is an imaginary number?

Comment: I have added an example. I think you mean that $x+yi$ is a complex number, right? So $y$ is the imaginary part of the complex number. Note that both $x$ and $y$ are real. It is $yi$, not $y$, that is imaginary.

Comment: Thank you!  Your added example helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to have helped. The problem is essentially that the ratio $y/x$ alone "forgets" the individual signs of $x$ and $y$, and "knows" only the net sign of the ratio. As you can now see, it is important to know both, because the ratio alone does not determine the location of the point.